# Apple Pay Flutter Payment is not made

Tags: ios, flutter, applepay

I have done the required settings as shown in document for Apple, but when I pay with the system’s bottom sheet choose the card and make the payment, the process is completed successfully, but the amount is not deducted and the reports are not shown in the developer account. I will attach pictures of my code to you

pay: ^1.0.11

the image and full descriptions in the link blew :

https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/issues/156

i found the solutions it :

Apple Pay on iOS does not process any payments. To make a payment you need a payment service provider (ie.: PSP). You can find a list of supported PSPs for Apple Pay in the [following link][1].

1-https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/payment-platforms/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it's close . i'm not have a PSP just it the problem

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to check is your configured card in Apple wallet, it could be disabled for online transactions. So if it is disabled, then you can still use it for POS and ATM, and won't work for online transactions, then you need to enabled it either through your bank or through their app, and most banks today have that feature where you can disable/enable your cards from using online transactions.

Second if you are well configured the Apple Pay configuration file, then it should works fine and see the generated token as well.

I will share here the comon configurations file where it should work for most users:

```
final String defaultApplePay = '''{
  "provider": "apple_pay",
  "data": {
    "merchantIdentifier": "merchant.co.test.App",
    "displayName": "App_Name",
    "merchantCapabilities": ["debit", "credit", "3DS"],
    "supportedNetworks": ["amex", "visa", "masterCard", "discover"],
    "countryCode": "QA",
    "currencyCode": "QAR",
    "requiredBillingContactFields": [],
    "requiredShippingContactFields": [],
    "shippingMethods": []
  }
}''';
```

Then you need only to replace these 3 keys, the `merchantIdentifier`, the `countryCode` and `currencyCode` to yours.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts
I solved it but I don't know about the stack over flow policies
Because he did not allow me to put the solution or the correct answer after my question, and thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the steps above, everything you did was correct, but the defect was related to the service provider and the country in which Apple Pay will be used. Thus, we used a payment gateway through a web browser so that it worked as a service provider and the process was completed successfully.